# Garbage on rotated screen when I rotate a certain monitor

Tags: 11.04, compiz, ati, dualhead

I have a really weird problem with ubuntu natty:
I have 2 monitors (Dell 2407wfp and Dell 2007wfp) connected via DVI to a Ati X1600 graphics card. Everything works well in normal configuration, but when I rotate the 2007wfp it displays only garbage (I can see the cursor like normal trough).

Funny thing is when I rotate the 2407wfp or both, everything is normal. I've tried to swap the connectors on the graphics card but that didn't change anything.

I am using the open source ati driver.

Answer (score 1):

So I resolved the issue by upgrading xorg using the [xorg-edgers ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa).

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)