# dual monitor, rotate secondary screen

Tags: ati, lubuntu, multiple-monitors, cinnamon

I run 2 screens on an AMD r9 280x card, and I need to rotate my secondary screen. 
When I try to do that via the display settings, my main screen gets all garbled up and is unusable. This happens with both proprietary and open source drivers.

My OS is Lubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have not had this problem with the lubuntu default LXDE, but the problem remains with mate, cinnamon, unity. have not tried with kde, but anyway I want to end up using cinnamon.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? I really need this second screen rotated due to space constraints at my desk, and compatibility with my dualbooted windows.

Things I have tried:

- try different drivers: proprietary, open source
- no inspiration for anything else so far :/

My first (main) screen: Dell U2515h, connected through Mini DisplayPort.

Second screen: Dell 2209WA, connected through hdmi and converted into DVI (only supports VGA and DVI input)

Rotating the main screen doesn't seem to give any problems.

Comment: Does it work OK if you rotate the primary? If so, would switching the positions of the primary and external be a solution? Also, please [edit] your question and tell us how the screen is connected. VGA? DVI? Something else?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. At this moment i can't test using a different video output on my graphics card, i don't have the appropriate cables. Is it any likely that this can solve the issue?

Comment: That what can solve it? I just asked what type of connection your screen has and whether it works if you rotate the primary instead. Just to get an idea.

Comment: Ah, OK, so, if you can rotate one and not the other, just switch them around. That should work.

Comment: one screen accepts only vga and dvi, the other only hdmi and (mini)displayport, so switching them around is no simple reconnecting of cables. Anyway, as i thought an alternative driver fixed my issue. thanks for your time anyway :)

Comment: Ah, no, I meant move them around physically so that the one you can rotate is on the side of your desk where you want the rotated one to be. Never mind if you solved it though. Well done! It would be great if you could remember to come back and accept your answer when the system lets you do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this other question i found, i used a different source for the Xorg drivers. this fixed my issue:

[Garbage on rotated screen when I rotate a certain monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34713/garbage-on-rotated-screen-when-i-rotate-a-certain-monitor?rq=1)